# Some class of *piecewise linear* map on finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ be a finite field of $2^n$ elements.

$H<\mathbb{F}_{2^n}^*$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}^* = \cup^{r-1}_{i=0}H_i$ is splitting into cosets of the nontrivial (multiplicative) subgroup $H$.

Let $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$. Consider a map $f : \mathbb{F}_{2^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $\exists A_0,A_1,\dots,A_{r-1} \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}^*$ such that $\forall x \in H_i$ $f(x) = x^{2^k}A_i$.

I'm trying to describe univariate polynomial representation of this map. It's easy to see that every adjacent class goes into another by mapping. Also we can see that restriction of $f$ on $H_i$ is $x^{2^k}A_i$. So I suppose that polynomial representation will be $f(x)|_{H_j}=\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}b_ix^{2^i}$ (for restriction). Can we say something about univariate representation of $f(x)$?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the mapping $f$ need not be a linear combination of powers of the Frobenius in general. If I guessed/interpreted the set up correctly, then in the particular example where $H=\{1\}$ is the trivial group, every function $f:\Bbb{F}_{2^n}\to\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ with the property $f(0)=0$ is of this form (allowing unconstrained choice of the $A_i$s).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, sory for mess in my question. Now its more correct. Of course, I mean that $H_i$ are cosets, $A_i \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}^*$ and $H$ is nontrivial.

Comment: Ok. But it is still impossible to always get that form. You see, a polynomial of the form
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_ix^{2^i}$$ is *additive*. That is, 
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$ for all $x,y\in\overline{\Bbb{F}_{2^n}}.$ Typically you can find elements $x,y$ such that $x,y$ and $x+y$ belong to three different cosets of $H$. But your scheme, by a suitable choice of the $A_i$s, allows for $f(x)$, $f(y)$ and $f(x+y)$ to be arbitrary. Meaning that the relation $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$ won't always hold. Probably something can be said about the resulting $f$, but I don't know what :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I agree that it was incorrect to say that $f(x)$ is a linear combination of powers of the Frobenius in general but the restriction of $f$ is equal of some restriction of a linear combination of powers of the Frobenius, isn't it?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, unfortunately I can't say something about resulting :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'll discard the constraint $A_j\ne 0$.

Composing $f$ with $x\mapsto x^{2^{n-k}}$ we can assume that $k=0$.

Then your function $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}\to \Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ satisfies $f(hb)=h f(b)$ for a generator $h$ of $H$ and all $b\in \Bbb{F}_{2^n}$.

$f$ is given by an element of $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}[x]/(x^{2^n}-x)$, thus it is represented uniquely by a polynomial $F\in \Bbb{F}_{2^n}[x]$ of degree $< 2^n$, which must satisfy

$$F(hx) -h F(x)\in (x^{2^n}-x) \Bbb{F}_{2^n}[x]$$

$\deg(F(hx) -h F(x)) < 2^n$ so it must be that $F(hx) -h F(x)=0$.

Whence $F\in x\Bbb{F}_{2^n}[x^e]$ where $e=|H|$ is the order of $h$.

Comment: Why you did you discard the constraint $A_j \not= 0$? For what reason we composing $f$ with $x \mapsto x^{2^{n-k}}$? Can you explain that if $k \not = 0$ we will the same result (if you mean that)?

Comment: May be if $F \in x\mathbb{F}_{2^n}[x^e]$ than $f$ is piecewise linear?

Comment: The case $k\ne 0$ is obtained by composing with $x\mapsto x^{2^k}$. I'm assuming that you don't have any good reason to assume that $A_i\ne 0$. Define "piecewise linear"...

Comment: There is a good reason to assume that $A_i \not= 0$. In that case if $f$(what defined in topic (lets call it "piecewise linear")) is a bijection (I have some results in that case) than it doing a permutation of  cosets of the nontrivial (multiplicative) subgroup. I think it will be interesting to describe class of polynomials what can give the same type of mapping.

Comment: $A_i\ne 0$ is not the same as $f$ is a bijection. And there is no good reason when asking for a simpler description of $f$. Still you haven't defined piecewise linear.

Comment: of course $A_i \not= 0$ is not same as $f$ is a bijection. I just tried to explain my idea why condition $A_i \not= 0$ is necessary. So lets define "piecewise linear" :-)

Comment: Let $f : \mathbb{F}_{2^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$. $f$ called k-piecewise linear if $f(0) = 0$ and $\exists A_0,A_1,\dots,A_{r-1} \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}^*$ such that $\forall x \in H_i$ $f(x) = x^{2^k}A_i$ $i \in \overline{0,r-1}$.

Comment: Of course, $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}^* = \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{r-1}H_i$ is  splitting into cosets of the nontrivial (multiplicative) subgroup $H < \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$.

Comment: Its easy to see that if $f$ is k-piecewise linear than $f$ is bijection when $\{a_i + i2^k | i \in \overline{0,r-1}\}$ is the full system of quotient modulo $r$, where $A_i = \theta^{a_i}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2^n} = <\theta>$.

Comment: My question was about how to describe the polynomial representation of $f$ which is "k-piecewise linear". My second question was about if $F\in x\mathbb{F}_{2^n}[x^e]$  is it enough to say that $f$ is "k-piecewise linear"?

Comment: Again you don't have any good reason to asumme that $A_j\ne 0$. When allowing $A_j=0$ then $f(hx)=h^{2^k} f(x)$ iff $f\in x^{2^k}\Bbb{F}_{2^n}[x^e]$ (modulo $x^{2^n}-x$)

Comment: allowing $A_j = 0$ make $f$ "bad". If $f$ is "k-piecewise linear" and for some $j$  we have $A_j = 0$ than $f(H_j) = \{0\}$ so $f$ in that case is not a bijection. I'm constructing "k-piecewise linear" map $f$ such that it can do a permutation of cosets. Also I can tried to describe its polynomial representation.

Comment: In other words I want to say that $A_i \not= 0$ is assumed initially in the condition)

Comment: please incorporate the new details of your question in the question body.